# Lagrangian formulation of the material derivative on a manifold

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, fluid-dynamics

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, the material derivative along a divergence free vector filed $\mathbf{u}$ is given by $\frac{D}{dt}=\partial_t+\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla$, and has the Lagrangian formulation

> Let $\gamma:\mathscr{D}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be the flow of $\mathbf{u}$ (where $\mathscr{D}\subset\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$ is its domain of definition). Then, for all vector fields $X$ $$\frac{D}{dt}X(t,\gamma(t,x))=\partial_tX(t,\gamma(t,x)),$$

i.e. the material derivative restricted to integral curves is the classical time derivative. My question is: what is the corresponding formulation on a Riemannian manofold $M$?

In this case, the material derivative is $\partial_t+\nabla_u$, and sends vector fields to vector fields. But something like $$\partial_t X(t,\gamma(t,x))$$ belongs to $TTM$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way of generalizing the definition you provide to $\mathbb{R}\times M$ makes use of the Levy-Civita connection. Let $X$ be a time dependent vector field on $M$, and let $U$ be the flow field. We can define the material derivative as
$$
\frac{D}{dt}X=\frac{d}{dt}X+\nabla_UX
$$
Where $\nabla_U$ is the covariant derivative. The LC connection also gives us a way of interpreting the derivative of a vector field along a curve, which reproduces the expression you provide.
$$
\left(\frac{D}{dt}X\right)(t,\gamma(x,t))=D_t(X(t,\gamma(x,t)))
$$
Where $D_t$ is the covariant derivative along the path $\gamma$, which is an integral curve of $U$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one detail: when you say $D_t$ the covariant derivative along $\gamma$ what do you mean, since $\gamma$ is a path and not a vector filed? You mean something like $\nabla_{\gamma'}$?

Comment: The covariant derivative $\nabla$ gives a way to differentiate along paths, even if those vector fields are not defined on the whole manifold (e.g. veclocity of a path). $D_t$ is just a name for this operator. If $V$ is a vector field along $\gamma$, and $\tilde{V}$ is a local extension of $V$, then it satisfies $$D_tV(t)=\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}(t)}\tilde{V}(\gamma(t))$$
See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Derivative_along_curve).